# Elasticsearch: Nested query under a boolean 'should' not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running the following query (it has been shortened for clarity):

```
body : {
        query : {
            bool : {
                must : [
                    {
                        match : {
                            active : 1
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                should : [
                      {
                        term : {
                            apply : '2'
                            }
                        },
                      {
                        nested : {
                            path : 'items',
                            query : {
                                terms : {
                                    'items.product' : ["1","2"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                minimum_should_match : 1
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

When I run this query, I don't pull back the documents that match the nested query in the should clause; I only pull back documents matching the first condition. What am I doing wrong? Why can't the terms query not test the field against an array of input items and return results?

When I change the nested query to a `match_all` or match the `items.product` field to an exact value, I do get results.

Changing the nested query into the following instead of the current nested query (while everything else stays the same) gives me no results either.

```
 nested : {
        path : 'items',
        query : {
            bool : {
                must : [
                    {
                        terms : {
                            'items.product' : ["1","2"],            
                             minimum_should_match : 1
                            }
                        },                          
                    ]
                }
            }
         }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - this has been driving me crazy for a couple days now!

Comment: Is there anything in your query that is performing any filtering based on score?

Comment: Nope, that's the entire query. That's what I thought at one point as well but it's just not the case.

Comment: Does the `items.product` field contain only a single integer (in string representation), or is there other character data in the field as well?

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED** to include discussion of the index mapping

Given that the `terms` condition expects a non-analyzed field (per the documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html)), I would recommend you verify that your index has a mapping that specifically makes it so.  For instance:

```
{"mappings" : {
  "your_doc_type" : {
    "items" : {
      "type" : "nested",
      "properties" : {
        "product" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        ...
        ... Other properties of the nested object
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
    ... Mappings for the other fields in your document type
    ...
  }
}
```

That should enable the `terms` to do what they are supposed to do when checking `items.product`.

My earlier suspicion was that there is something else in your query (`min_score` perhaps) that is filtering out results based upon score, and that threshold is weeding out the documents that match the `items.product` condition but not the `apply` condition due to the underlying Lucene scoring model.  In other words, if all other things are equal for documents meeting only one item of the `should` query, the ones that meet the `"apply":"2"` condition will score higher than the documents for which `items.product` is 1 or 2.  This was my empirical observation querying a trivially small test set of data with your query.

Test data set:

```
{"active":1, "apply":"2", "items" : [{"product": "3"}]}
{"active":0, "apply":"2", "items" : [{"product": "3"}]}
{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "3"}]}
{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "1"}]}
{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "2"}]}
```

Based on the conditions in your query, we should see three documents returned - the first, fourth, and fifth documents.

```
"hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "AUtrND1rIJ0nixSnh_cG",
  "_score" : 0.731233,
  "_source":{"active":1, "apply":"2", "items" : [{"product": "3"}]}
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "AUtrND1sIJ0nixSnh_cK",
  "_score" : 0.4601705,
  "_source":{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "2"}]}
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "AUtrND1sIJ0nixSnh_cJ",
  "_score" : 0.35959372,
  "_source":{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "1"}]}
} ]
```

The expected documents came back, but you can see that the first document (for which `apply` is 2, meeting the first criterion of the `should` query) scored much higher.

If your intent is for these conditions to not affect the scoring of the documents but to use them instead as simple inclusion/exclusion criteria, you may want to switch to a filtered query.  Something like:

```
{
  "query" : {"filtered" : {
    "query" : {"match_all" : {}},
    "filter" : {"bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {"term" : {"active" : 1}}
      ],
      "should" : [
        {"term" : {"apply" : "2"}},
        {"nested" : {
          "path": "items",
          "query" : {
            "terms" : {"items.product" : ["1", "2"]}
          }
        }}
      ]
    }}
  }}
}
```

Since you are now specifying a filter instead, these conditions should not impact the scoring of the returned documents but instead only determine whether a document qualifies at all for the result set (the scores are then calculated independently of the conditions above).  Using this filtered query, the results from my dumb data set are:

```
"hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "AUtrND1rIJ0nixSnh_cG",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"active":1, "apply":"2", "items" : [{"product": "3"}]}
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "AUtrND1sIJ0nixSnh_cK",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "2"}]}
}, {
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "test",
  "_id" : "AUtrND1sIJ0nixSnh_cJ",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"active":1, "apply":"3", "items" : [{"product": "1"}]}
} ]
```

The scores are now identical for all returned documents, without regard for which part of the `should` was satisfied.

Note that the `query` property above is `match_all` - if you had other conditions in your query that are not represented in the original question, then you would need to modify this accordingly.

Comment: Actually, interestingly enough I did start out with the filtered query originally, and then reverted to the basic query when running into problems. This solution unfortunately doesn't work, and to make things even odder, when I remove the 'apply : 2' condition entirely (while leaving the nested condition), I get back no results at all. When I use the match query on the nested field 'item.product' to match to a specific string, it works perfectly. It seems to me that the terms query is not working.

Comment: @aamirl Do you have an explicit mapping defined for this index, specifically the nested object field?

Comment: No, I don't actually, and that was another thing I checked and made sure about before posting; the mapping for the field is a simple string. As I mentioned before, doing a match or a term query/filter on the field to an input string leads to results. It's only when trying to use a terms query (and passing in an array to compare it to) that it fails. =/

Comment: @aamirl That is possibly part of the issue then - I think `terms` (both the filter and query versions) is meant to be an exact match of the entire field, and even then the field's `index` property in the mapping should be specified as `not_analyzed`.  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html

Comment: I agree that they are meant to be exact matches on an item in the input field, but this doesn't seem to be the issue here because one of the items I am testing it against in the input array matches exactly with the nested 'item.product' field.

Comment: @aamirl You want to see if adding an explicit mapping which defines that nested object field as `not_analyzed` gets you better results.  I've updated the top section of my answer to reflect that.